# Can I restore discarded files from Visual studio git changes?

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio

I accidentally discarded files that generated migrations. I have migration code, I lost the rest of the files.

Is there a way to restore it?

Comment: If you don't have another copy of them and they weren't committed (which they weren't since you wouldn't have been able to discard them), then no. You'll have to recreate them.

Comment: Wow this is really bad design. An accidental click and you can lose thousands of lines of new code, and it isn't even sent to the Recycle Bin? Just wow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discarded not committed code is lost.

If you have migrations, you can migrate in a database and generate your Model POCO files with EDMX.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/workflows/database-first